# While 3 * 0.1 cannot be represented exactly, why can Javascript properly calculate 0.15 * 2?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Floating-Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

In Javascript,

```
3 * 0.1 = 0.30000000000000004
```

I think this is due to the language's number system where 0.3 cannot be accurately represented. But why the following?

```
0.15 * 2 = 0.3
```

Similarly,

```
0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004
```

But

```
0.15 + 0.15 = 0.3
```

How's so?

Comment: Here's a good place to learn more about floating point arithmetic: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). The JS interpreter is relying on the underlying libraries and/or floating point hardware of the host to perform floating point arithmetic, which implement the IEEE 754 floating point standard. You can test particular values at an [online IEEE 754 floating point evaluator](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html). As you've discovered, some values will have rounding/truncati

Comment: Rounding sometimes does it right, sometimes not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But why the following?
>
> 0.15 * 2 = 0.3

The result isn't exactly 0.3, but it's close enough so that when the least significant digits are rounded off to display the value, it's rounded to 0.3.

The values `0.1` and `0.15` are not exact either, but the error representing `0.1` seems to be larger than for `0.15`. When you use the values in calculations, the errors accumulate, and sooner or later they become large enough not to be rounded off when the values are displayed.

Comment: can you better explain the rounding logics when it comes to display it? I guess `toFixed` would show the error

Comment: @Bertuz: The number is just rounded to a few digits less than what the data type can represent, which will remove most errors that the limitation of the data type causes. When you see a number like `0.3` displayed, it has first been rounded to something like `0.3000000000000000`, then the trailing zeroes are just omitted. The `toFixed` function can be used to show the exact value, at least in most browsers. I tested that in Chrome, and it will happily show you up to 100 digits.