# Why js can print decimal 0.1 accurately? How does approximation(rounding) works when converting floating-point back to decimal?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I know why decimal can not be represented in floating-point accurately. I also know it will be rounded when convert decimal to floating-point according to IEEE 754.

But, now that the actual floating-point is not accurate, for example decimal 0.1 will be rounded in floating-point: 
`0,01111111011,1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010`

the infinite representation is:
`0.000110011001...(infinte 1001)`

When we print the 0.1 in decimal, the floating-point representation should be convert to decimal, the question is how the rounded floating-point representation can be rounded "accurately"?

I find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251052/while-3-0-1-cannot-be-represented-exactly-why-can-javascript-properly-calcula), @Guffa say:

> it's close enough so that when the least significant digits are rounded off to display the value

But I don't understand how the rounding works **when converting floating-point back to decimal**

I do not know if I have made it clear, but I really want to know why.

Thanks.

Comment: I **know** this is a duplicate, but it's going to be really hard to find the dupetarget.

Comment: Turns out, it wasn't that hard to find.